# Getting issue in url Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The URL working fine with 
http://localhost/townlabour4/tl/DjKammu

but when I put '/' after that issue created. 
http://localhost/townlabour4/tl/DjKammu/

It goes to http://localhost/DjKammu
with error Object not found.

Comment: show your routes file

Comment: replace DjKammu with /DjKAmmu   or vice versa in your routes file

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/{home}', 'societyController@home');

Route::get('/{home}/admin', 'societyController@admin');

Comment: @AdamKozlowski Here route files

Comment: The routes you posted and the URL you mentioned in your question, do not match.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay bro  http://localhost/townlabour4/tl is url and Djkammmu is dynamic value as it called in 2nd route

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to stick with non-trailing slash. 
Easiest way is to add `.htaccess` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

or with `Nginx` in `server` block:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```